# Running a script file over ssh through sudo

Tags: bash, ssh, sudo, here-document

I can log in to a remote machine as a user who can do `sudo su -`. I can't login as root.

I have a script locally that I want to run at the remote machine. Also, the script is sent there trough another script.

I can't figure out how. I've red quite a few Q&A's here but no success. The closest I have:

```
COMMAND_SSH="sudo -i <<\'EOF\'"`cat ./unifyServiceNode.sh`"\\nEOF\\n" ;;
...
while read HOST; do
  echo -e "\n\n======== $USER_@$HOST <-- $COMMAND_SSH =================\n\n";
  ssh -n -tt centos@$HOST "'$COMMAND_SSH'";
done < hosts.txt
```

This ends up with this output:

```
======== centos@somehost.com <-- sudo -i <<\'EOF\'
##
##  Creates a few links and scripts to unify the nodes maintainance.
##

  BB="/bb"
  NAME="bpds-api"
  NAME2="bpds-"

  mkdir -p $BB
  ln -s /opt/$NAME/logs/*.log $BB/log
  ln -s /opt/$NAME/conf/api/$NAME.yml $BB/conf.yml || ln -s /opt/$NAME/conf/api/$NAME2.yml $BB/conf.yml
  echo "systemctl \${1:-restart} "${@:2}" $NAME" > $BB/Sys
  echo "tail -\${1:-500f} $BB/log" > $BB/Tail
  echo "nano $BB/conf.yml" > $BB/Conf
  chmod a+x $BB/Sys $BB/Tail $BB/Conf
  echo "export PATH=\$PATH:$BB" >> ~/.bashrc
EOF
 =====================================


bash: sudo -i <<\EOF': command not found
bash: line 14: /bb/Sys: Permission denied
bash: line 15: /bb/Tail: Permission denied
bash: line 16: /bb/Conf: Permission denied
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/bb/Sys’: Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/bb/Tail’: Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/bb/Conf’: Operation not permitted
bash: -c: line 18: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 19: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Connection to somehost.com closed.
```

This is the "closest" because it sees the individual commands but is not under `sudo`, because the first line's `<<EOF` isn't (un)escaped properly.

**How should I execute an arbitrary script under `sudo` over `ssh`?"

Comment: Why do you want to put a command in a variable?

Answer (score 3):

I have figured out soon after posting.

```
COMMAND_SSH="sudo -i <<'EOF'"`cat ./unifyServiceNode.sh``echo -e '\nEOF'` ;;

ssh -n -tt centos@$HOST "$COMMAND_SSH"; ## -n prevents reading the input. -tt forces TTY.
```

The extra `'`s around the SSH command were the issue it seems, and I also needed to make the newline through `echo`.

I am not quite sure if that's just a lucky hack or the right way to do it, though. To be honest, I am completely lost in Bash's quotes evaluation :)

Answer (score 1):

Your current method is very convoluted, which is what's making it difficult to work with.
This can instead be simplified to:

```
ssh -i $AWS_KEY centos@$HOST sudo sh < ./unifyServiceNode.sh
```

Comment: Doesn't work in my case. For `ssh` to run sudo, it needs `-tt`, otherwise I get `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`. And if I use `-tt`, then `<` redirection is ignored.

Comment: you can overcome the requirement for TTY by setting in the `sudoers` file:
`requiretty=off`.  If set, sudo will only run when the user is logged in to a real tty.  When this flag is set, sudo can only be run from a login session and not via other means such as cron(8) or cgi-bin scripts.  This flag is off by default.

Answer (score 0):

Put the commands that you need to execute in a script, transfer that script over to the host using `scp` and run it through `ssh`.

Or, feed the here-document to the appropriate shell:

```
ssh server sh <<'END_SCRIPT'
script code
goes here
END_SCRIPT
```

Or, use Ansible or similar system which is made for remote configuration of multiple hosts.

You generally do not want to put commands in variables.

Comment: Sure, but I wanted to do this in one step. Ideal would be some kind of `scpAndRun` command.

Comment: Regarding commands in variables - I have a 2 pass script that creates the command in one part, and the way to execute it on remote servers is in other part. Is there other mechanism for that than a variable which I could use in one step with ssh?

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to store plain text passwords (obviously a bad idea), you can combine `sshpass -p "my_ssh_password"`, `ssh << HEREDOC` and `echo "my_sudo_password" | sudo -S my_cmd` to do it.

Example:

```
sshpass -p "my_ssh_password" ssh my_user@my_ip << 'ENDSSH'
echo "my_sudo_password" | sudo -S my_sudo_command1
echo "my_sudo_password" | sudo -S my_sudo_command2
echo "my_sudo_password" | sudo -S my_sudo_script
ENDSSH
```